# Fast way of getting a page source

Tags: python, html

I am currently using Selenium to open and retrieve the page source of a list of urls. However Selenium is taking way too long for each url and I plan on using this script for (atleast) a couple of hundred urls. Can anyone suggest a faster method of getting the page source given a url (using php maybe?)?

Please include the code of your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

```
browser.get(url)
body = browser.page_source
```

Comment: or: https://3.python-requests.org/

Comment: @BramVanroy does urllib2 give you access to the html code so that it can be parsed by beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob.

But I think requests might be faster, followed by headless browsers (Selenium, but doesn't open a GUI) and then finally, regular Selenium. I'm basing my thinking on the resources each method might use.

Unfortunately I can't find any articles that time the difference between these methods, but here's an article that seems to cover the chrome headless browser: https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/

Comment: I am not using GUI. I just want the source.

Comment: You should use requests and see how much quicker that is. If you're using Selenium, you're likely using GUI.